# How to resolve error Code 403 from Cowin Public API in android studio?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rest

Here's the link to the Cowin Public API:

1. https://apisetu.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin#/
2. https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states

I have been trying to get the state details from the 2nd link in android studio using retrofit library. But every time I run the app it's showing error 403. Any help would be appreciated!! Adding my code below:

1. On create activity:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        CovidAPI covidAPI = retrofit.create(CovidAPI.class);

        Call<StateMainModel> call = covidAPI.getAllIndiaStates();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<StateMainModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StateMainModel> call, Response<StateMainModel> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error!!Code: "+response.code()+response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tv.setText(response.toString());
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    StateMainModel stateMainModel = response.body();

                    int size = stateMainModel.getStates().size();

                    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                    {
                        stateList.add(stateMainModel.getStates().get(i).getState_name());
                    }

                    stateAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StateMainModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error!! Response: "+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

2. API Interface

```
@GET("v2/admin/location/states")
    Call<StateMainModel> getAllIndiaStates();
```

3. StateMainModel Model Class

```
private ArrayList<StateIdNameModel> states;
    private Integer ttl;

    public StateMainModel() {
    }

    public StateMainModel(ArrayList<StateIdNameModel> states,Integer ttl) {
        this.states = states;
        this.ttl = ttl;
    }

    public ArrayList<StateIdNameModel> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(ArrayList<StateIdNameModel> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    public Integer getTtl() {
        return ttl;
    }

    public void setTtl(Integer ttl) {
        this.ttl = ttl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Java Code that worked for me:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                Request requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36").build();
                return  chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent);


            }
        }).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an object of class OkHttpClient and then you will have to add interceptor to it since it requires key to access the api

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the User-Agent in your request to get a successful response. See the below Kotlin code:

```
val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = Level.BODY}
okHttpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor { chain ->
                    chain.proceed(chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")
                        .build())
}.addNetworkInterceptor(logger)
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/")
                .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

Comment: Okay, that is something new to which I came across today. Do you have any idea how do I set user-agent in Java?

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996219/6147653

Comment: Thanks buddy!! It worked. btw why do we need to use this?

Comment: They have restricted the API only for browsers, So I tried it with the browser user agent and it worked.